# Python and Tkinter: Classes and instance creation error

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two classes and am trying to create a button with a command to call a method in another class. I'm currently experiencing issues creating an instance because I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'number_queue'
```

which is a variable referenced in Widgets and the Widgets method.

Any pointers would be welcome, I always struggle with instances and cross class referencing. One of my main issues is if I created an instance like:

```
instance1 = Widgets(self,master,queue_type, symbol, examples)
```

What do I put in the instance variables?
And what do I need to put in the Queue class.

This is the class with the button referencing widgets

```
class Queue(tk.Frame):
    """A Tkinter grid"""

    def __init__(self, master, columns, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Construct a new grid

        Parameters:
            master (tk.Tk|tk.Frame): Frame containing this widget
            columns (int): Amount of columns in the grid
        """
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)

        self._row = 0
        #self._callback = Widgets.remove_student_tick
        ##self.awidget = Widgets()
        # configure the grid to fill the space
        for column in range(columns):
            tk.Grid.columnconfigure(self, column, weight=1)

    def add_student_row(self, first_last, number,questions_asked):

        column1= number
        column2 = first_last
        column3 = questions_asked
        column4 = ''
        column5 = ''
        values= [column1, column2, column3, column4, column5]

        for column, value in enumerate(values):
            label = tk.Label(self, text=value)
            label.grid(row=self._row, column=column, sticky=tk.W, ipadx = 10)

        self._row += 1


        cross = Button(self, bg='red', command =Widgets.remove_student_tick(self, first_last)
        cross.grid(column = 5)
```

And this is the class and method I am referencing.

```
class Widgets(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master,queue_type, symbol, examples, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
    ***some irrelavant code****
    def remove_student_tick(self, first_last):
    ***some irrelavant code***
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
Traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\AlexLaptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args) 
   File "C:\Users\AlexLaptop\Desktop\CSSE A3\GUI.py", line 77, in callback
    self._grid.add_student_row(first_last,number, self._q_student_queue[first_last])
  File "C:\Users\AlexLaptop\Desktop\CSSE A3\GUI.py", line 209, in add_student_row
    cross = Button(self, bg='red', command = Widgets.remove_student_tick(self, first_last))
  File "C:\Users\AlexLaptop\Desktop\CSSE A3\GUI.py", line 86, in remove_student_tick
    index = self.number_queue.index(first_last)
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'number_queue'
{'asd': 0, 'aasd': 0}
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AlexLaptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\AlexLaptop\Desktop\CSSE A3\GUI.py", line 77, in callback
    number = self.number_queue.index(first_last) + 1
  File "C:\Users\AlexLaptop\Desktop\CSSE A3\GUI.py", line 209, in add_student_row
  File "C:\Users\AlexLaptop\Desktop\CSSE A3\GUI.py", line 86, in remove_student_tick
    def remove_student_tick(self, first_last):
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'number_queue'
```

With Widgets instead of Frame:

```
File "C:\Users\AlexLaptop\Desktop\CSSE A3\GUI.py", line 227, in main
    app = App(root)
  File "C:\Users\AlexLaptop\Desktop\CSSE A3\GUI.py", line 126, in __init__
    quick_frame = Widgets(quickFrame, "Quick", "<", quick_examples)
  File "C:\Users\AlexLaptop\Desktop\CSSE A3\GUI.py", line 48, in __init__
    self._grid = Queue(self, 4)
  File "C:\Users\AlexLaptop\Desktop\CSSE A3\GUI.py", line 172, in __init__
    super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'queue_type', 'symbol', and 'examples'
```

Comment: Can you please post the complete traceback?

Comment: Maybe you could make your `Queue` subclass your `Widget` class, something like: `class Queue(tk.Frame, Widgets):`.

Comment: Added Traceback

Comment: TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases Frame, Widgets    - This is the error i get when I do that, thanks for the help though

Comment: Yes, ok, sorry, then `Queue` shouldn't subclass `Frame` as it is already subclassed by `Widgets`...

Comment: Check edits, got an error from when I called the Queue class in another location, I never know what to put as the attributes in these situations

Comment: I'm a bit lost as for what you're trying to do, could you please reduce your example to a minimal, complete and verifiable example? Or try to explain what you're doing. For example: why don't you define the `remove_student_tick` method inside the `Queue` class? What's the need of the `Widget` class? What's the relation between the two classes?

Comment: Post a proper MCVE if you hope to get any help (please read this for a definition of "mcve" : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You have some other issues that will cause your code to fail. For example your cross button command is incorrect. If you need to pass some arguments then you will need to use a lambda here.

Comment: Your traceback refers to `self.number_queue.index(first_last)` however you have nothing like this in your code example.